# Amazon Ads Don't Refresh through Handler

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I read from the amazon website that they do not have a default update mechanism (as compared to AdMob etc.). As such, I tried to update the amazon ads manually but there was the following error:

```
E/AmazonAppstore.AppManagerService﹕ asinList: null
com.amazon.assertion.AssertionException: asinList: null
        at com.amazon.assertion.Assert.fail(Assert.java:203)
        at com.amazon.assertion.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:22)
        at com.amazon.mas.client.locker.service.appmgr.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate.handleAppInsertion(AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate.java:113)
        at com.amazon.mas.client.locker.service.appmgr.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate.handleIntent(AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate.java:76)
        at com.amazon.mas.client.locker.service.appmgr.AppManagerService.onHandleIntent(AppManagerService.java:96)
        at com.amazon.android.service.IntentTimeoutService.handleIntent(IntentTimeoutService.java:253)
        at com.amazon.android.service.IntentTimeoutService.access$000(IntentTimeoutService.java:27)
        at com.amazon.android.service.IntentTimeoutService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentTimeoutService.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

In onCreate:

```
AdRegistration.setAppKey(MyAppKey(correct))
        AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);     
        AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);
        this.adView = (AdLayout) findViewById(R.id.adview);
        adView.loadAd();
         timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
```

Run method:

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        time++;
        if (time%60000==0) {
        AdRegistration.enableLogging(true);
        AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);
            adView.loadAd();}}
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
};
```